# opening a link in a new window

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net

I need to open the link in the link button in a new window. I have the  below code but  it throws javascript error. Please help

aspx code:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="Link" runat="server" CssClass="ReadOnlyLabel" 
                        CausesValidationn="false" OnClick="Link_Click"/>
```

code behind

```
protected void Link_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "OPEN_WINDOW", 
                      "window.open(" + Link.Text + " ,'new_tab');", true);
}
```

Comment: And the error is...?

Comment: put singlequotes around `" + Link.Text + "` and use onClientClick="" instead of onClick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

```
Uri uri = new Uri(LinkButton.Text);
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, Page.GetType(), "", "window.open('" + uri.OriginalString + "');", true);
```

Answer (score 3):

Better to use Hypelink in that scenario, it has target option to do that:-

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="Link" runat="server" CssClass="ReadOnlyLabel" 
                  CausesValidationn="false" Target="_blank">Click Here</asp:HyperLink>
```

Just set `NavigateUrl` property to set window url, and set `Target` property as `_blank`.

Comment: I cannot use the hyperlink as there will be different urls for that link

Comment: @Namekal, why dont you just set the url in your code behind?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),  
"window.open('" + Link.Text + "' ,'new_tab');", true);
```

EDIT

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),  
@"window.open('https://www.google.co.in/' ,'new_tab');", true);
```

So it Becomes

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),  
"window.open('https://" + Link.Text + "' ,'new_tab');", true);
```

Comment: I tried this and it opens a new window with an error as the link it's trying to open say www.abc.com is prefixed with http://localhost/myproject/www.abc.com. Please let me know how to fix that

Comment: Link.Text has "www.abc.com" but when the link is opened it tries to open my application name plus the link.text

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite the novice with aspx, but surely this would be of interest?

```
onclick="window.open (this.href, 'popupwindow', 'width=500,height=500,scrollbars,resizable')
```

http://forums.asp.net/t/1162787.aspx?How+to+open+hyperlink+in+new+window+without+any+tools+displayed+